# How to produce a binary variable that takes value of 0 before the last non-zero value of another variable and 1 after it

Tags: r

Given the variable

```
a <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I would like to mark the last non-zero value to produce a variable that takes value of 0 before the benchmark and 1 after it. In this case

```
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

A simple command that allows to mark the last non-zero value of a a column is

```
tail(which(a!=0),1)
```

But how to create the variable I need conditional on such benchmark? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which` to get the position, index where a is 1, wrap with `max` to return the last position, create a logical vector with sequence of 'a' and coerce to binary (`+`)

```
+(seq_along(a) >= max(which(a == 1)))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

Or use `Position`

```
+(seq_along(a) >= Position(function(x) x == 1, a, right = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
+(cumsum(a) == max(cumsum(a)))

 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Or:

```
+(cumsum(a) == sum(a))
```